# Swift Detect UISlider image tap

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uislider

So I have a `UISlider` that looks like this:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu2rF.png)

It is set up like this, so the images are not `UIImageView`'s, but images in the `UISlider`:
[Image 2 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23dPX.png)

I want to add a function so when the user press the image on left side, it runs one function, and when the user presses the image on the right side, it runs another function. Is this even possible?

Comment: share code which you implement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),  visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it. Please read the comments carefully.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // This is linked to your storyboard layout
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add a tap gesture recognizer to the slider
        slider.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sliderTapped(_:))))
    }

    @objc private func sliderTapped(_ tapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = tapRecognizer.location(in: slider)
        
        // UISlider can tell you min/max value image frames
        // CAUTION: Use images those are big enough to be easy tap targets
        // In my case, I used images of size 30x30
        let minImageRect = slider.minimumValueImageRect(forBounds: slider.bounds)
        let maxImageRect = slider.maximumValueImageRect(forBounds: slider.bounds)
        
        // Now you can check which image out of min/max was tapped
        if minImageRect.contains(location) {
            print("Min Image Tapped")
        } else if maxImageRect.contains(location) {
            print("Max Image Tapped")
        }
    }

}
```